# Access denied for user 'name'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a cron job in which it will send a mail when my inventory stocks are low. The email is just sending me the error code above, even though my database settings are accurate. So here is my code:

```
<?php

//I just renamed them, but you get the concept
$db_host = "mydbhost";
$db_username = "myusername";
$db_password = "mypassword";
$db_name = "mydatabase";

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_password,$db_name) or die ('MySQL Not found // Could Not Connect.');

$recipient = "email@email.com";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT prod_count, restock_level FROM mydatabase WHERE prod_count <= restock_level;");
if ($result) {
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  $count = $row['prod_count'];
  $restocklvl = $row['restock_level'];
  if ($count <= $restocklvl) {
    $msg = "Your inventory is currently low. Please restock.";
    mail($recipient, "Inventory check below threshold", $msg);
  }
}
else {
  $msg = "An error occurred while checking inventory: " . mysql_error();
  mail($recipient, "Inventory check error", $msg);
}
?>
```

What seems to go wrong? Thanks! [Here is the image of the email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLriU.png)

Comment: Because you are mixing `mysql and mysqli` in your code!!

Comment: If you are using mysqli keyword for DB interaction then you must need to use mysqli for your all CURD operations...

Comment: @Saty: the question is access denied . he used mysqli_connect for connecting db. so here is the problem (access is denied) .what i think is grand permission problem.And also he has mysqli and mysql mixing problem

Comment: have your problem sloved?

Comment: Thank you all guys! it's all fine now!

Comment: @VigneswaranS its not a access denied problem from database . This message also appears when something wrong in our query or we mixing mysql and mysqli.

Comment: @Saty: my wonder. now only i came to know this. thank you.but i will try locally with mixing mysqli and mysql(then i should get access denied)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<?php

//I just renamed them, but you get the concept
$db_host = "mydbhost";
$db_username = "myusername";
$db_password = "mypassword";
$db_name = "mydatabase";

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_password,$db_name) or die ('MySQL Not found // Could Not Connect.');

$recipient = "email@email.com";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT prod_count, restock_level FROM mydatabase WHERE prod_count <= restock_level;");
if ($result) {
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  $count = $row['prod_count'];
  $restocklvl = $row['restock_level'];
  if ($count <= $restocklvl) {
    $msg = "Your inventory is currently low. Please restock.";
    mail($recipient, "Inventory check below threshold", $msg);
  }
}
else {
  $msg = "An error occurred while checking inventory: " . mysqli_error($conn);
  mail($recipient, "Inventory check error", $msg);
}
?>
```

try this code.You mix mysql or mysqli code.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently mixing up the mysqli and mysql querys.  When connecting via mysqli you cannot user functions like mysql_query.

Code should be something along the lines of as a quick example:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_password,$db_name)
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

You'll have to change any mysql_ methods to the new mysqli in order for it to work correctly.

Comment: You need to reword your answer; also you are mixing procedural and OO styles.